# How to deploy webapp and webjob in same pipeline for .net framework project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-appservice

I have an ASP.NET MVC application (not .NET Core) which I am deploying to an Azure App Service using Azure Devops and a yaml file. It's working fine but I've another console application in the same solution and I want to deploy that as a webjob in the same app service.

I can't find any good help with .NET framework. All the links I found are demonstrating in .NET Core.

Here is my yaml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and Test Package
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Test_Publish
    displayName: Build_Test_Publish
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
      displayName: 'Install Visual Studio Test Platform'
      inputs:
        packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
        versionSelector: 'latestStable'

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        feedsToUse: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: './'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build Solution'
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'


- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'PROD'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: none
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
              
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: 'mySubscription'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: 'myWebApp'
              packageForLinux: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/Web.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a .NET framework Web job, you need to put it in a specific folder like `App_Data/jobs/continuous` for continuous Web Jobs and   `App_Data/jobs/triggered` for scheduled or on-demand Web Jobs .

The following script must be added to the  .YAML file .

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
inputs:
command: 'publish'
publishWebProjects: true
arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
zipAfterPublish: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
inputs:
command: 'publish'
publishWebProjects: false
projects: '**/*webjob.csproj'
arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/YoutubeWebJob'
zipAfterPublish: false
modifyOutputPath: false
```

The first task will add a the web app the later one will add a web job in this it is a continuous Web job .

refer this [tutorial](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/azure-webapp-with-webjobs-dotnet-core-build-depoy/?msclkid=51bc6a9bb1af11ec881330c1af9a79cb) to deploy Web job and webapp together in one pipeline .

refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs?msclkid=ad45bcddb2d911ecbe15fcadf58813c6) on how to deploy .NET framework Web jobs .